# Could not resolve org.kodein.di:kodein-di-framework-android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, jcenter, kodein

#### TL; DR

Access to Kodein core packages at JCenter are unauthorized.

#### Details

We are using Kodein for dependency injection, but suddenly JCenter server is returning `Unauthorized` when Gradle tries to download any `org.kodein.*` artifact.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve org.kodein.di:kodein-di-framework-android-x:6.1.0.
    Required by:
        project :app
    > Could not resolve org.kodein.di:kodein-di-framework-android-x:6.1.0.
        > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/org/kodein/di/kodein-di-framework-android-x/6.1.0/kodein-di-framework-android-x-6.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jitpack.io/org/kodein/di/kodein-di-framework-android-x/6.1.0/kodein-di-framework-android-x-6.1.0.pom'.
              Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
> Could not resolve org.kodein.di:kodein-di-generic-jvm:6.1.0.
    Required by:
        project :app
    > Could not resolve org.kodein.di:kodein-di-generic-jvm:6.1.0.
        > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/org/kodein/di/kodein-di-generic-jvm/6.1.0/kodein-di-generic-jvm-6.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jitpack.io/org/kodein/di/kodein-di-generic-jvm/6.1.0/kodein-di-generic-jvm-6.1.0.pom'.
              Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

It also has being reported as an [issue by Kodein-DI community](https://github.com/Kodein-Framework/Kodein-DI/issues/192).

Is it possible to obtain the artifacts from another server?

Answer (score 3):

While access to JCenter is not reestablished, this quick hacked allowed to compile the project:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap'
            content {
                includeGroup "org.kodein"
            }
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kodein-framework/Kodein-DI' }
    }
}
```

Basically it ignores Kodein artifacts from JitPack and downloads them from Bintray instead

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in your project level build.gradle file and sync project:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {url "https://jitpack.io"}
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kodein-framework/Kodein-DI" }
    }
}
```

[Visit for More Details](https://answerdone.blogspot.com/)